# How do I make my responsive Navbar sticky with only HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sticky

So I currently have a navbar that is responsive to the size of the screen built with HTML & CSS only. But I want it to stick to the container and also remain responsive to different screen sizes. Is there anyway to do this with only HTML & CSS? I have included the responsive Navbar code in this post that I would to update and make sticky.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    float: left;
  }
  div.content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
    <p>This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen size is 700px or less.</p>
    <p>We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack and center the navigation links.</p>
    <h3>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h3>
  </div>

</body>

</html>

```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need `position: fixed;` and an actualy position like `top: 0;`.

But also you could use the `position: sticky;` property instead to avoid overlapping content, like the other answer mentioned. [Here you can see the browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) which is pretty good for position sticky, but slightly worse than fixed.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    float: left;
  }
  div.content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
    <p>This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen size is 700px or less.</p>
    <p>We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack and center the navigation links.</p>
    <h3>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h3>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `position:sticky;` and `top:0` in your first media query to keep the navbar in place at the top, even when you scroll. This will work better than `position:fixed` because the content won't slide up behind the header while you are at the top.

Edit - embedded code directly.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sidebar a {
  display: block;
  color: black;
  padding: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar a.active {
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

div.content {
  margin-left: 200px;
  padding: 1px 16px;
  height: 1000px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    float: left;
  }
  div.content {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .sidebar a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="sidebar">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <h2>Responsive Sidebar Example</h2>
    <p>This example use media queries to transform the sidebar to a top navigation bar when the screen size is 700px or less.</p>
    <p>We have also added a media query for screens that are 400px or less, which will vertically stack and center the navigation links.</p>
    <h3>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h3>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Instead of a codepen, you can add code right into your answer. Give it a try 